Linear Regression Using Normal Equation using @ symbol
Write a Python function that performs linear regression using the normal equation. The function should take a matrix X (features) and a vector y (target) as input, and return the coefficients of the linear regression model. Round your answer to four decimal places, -0.0 is a valid result for rounding a very small number.
Example:
        input: X = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]], y = [1, 2, 3]
        output: [0.0, 1.0]
        reasoning: The linear model is y = 0.0 + 1.0*x, perfectly fitting the input data.

my function:
import numpy as np
def linear_regression_normal_equation(X: list[list[float]], y: list[float]) -> list[float]:
    theta = np.linalg.inv(np.transpose(X) @ X) @ np.transpose(X) @ y
    return theta

result:
Input:
print(linear_regression_normal_equation([[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]], [1, 2, 3]))
Output:
[-1.77635684e-15  1.00000000e+00]
Expected:
[-0.0, 1.0]

one of the solutions:
import numpy as np
def linear_regression_normal_equation(X: list[list[float]], y: list[float]) -> list[float]:
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1)
    X_transpose = X.T
    theta = np.linalg.inv(X_transpose.dot(X)).dot(X_transpose).dot(y)
    theta = np.round(theta, 4).flatten().tolist()
    return theta

Let's ignore the format(round, tolist) for a while.
I think my function and the correct one are doing the same thing. Please help me.

It seems to me that your result and the expected result are essentially identical. The difference is superficial, and arises from your not rounding your result. If you take the last (pre-return) lines of your example solution and add it to your solution, your results should align.

Thank you for your patience. I done what you told and it worked perfectly!

They are the same answers, just rounded differently.
Try changing the round() to:
  theta = np.round(theta, 1).flatten().tolist()

